# How can I change this list of buttons/menus so that only one menu is visible at a time?

Tags: javascript, toggle

Here is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".btn1").click(function(){
        $(".menu1").toggle();
    });
    $(".btn2").click(function(){
        $(".menu2").toggle();
    });
    $(".btn3").click(function(){
        $(".menu3").toggle();
    });
    $(".btn4").click(function(){
        $(".menu4").toggle();
    });
});
```

```css
#button{
    height : 35px;
    line-height : 35px;
    text-align : center;
    background-color : grey;
    border-top : 2px solid white;
    border-bottom : 2px solid white;
}
#menu_to_show{
    border: 2px solid orange;
    height : 50px;
}
.menu1, .menu2, .menu3, .menu4{ display : none; }
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="button" class="btn1">Button 1</div>
<div id="menu_to_show" class="menu1">
    This is text which belong to button 1.
</div>
<div id="button" class="btn2">Button 2</div>
<div id="menu_to_show" class="menu2">
    This is another text. This appear after you click on button 2.
</div>
<div id="button" class="btn3">Button 3</div>
<div id="menu_to_show" class="menu3">
    Some text under button 3.
</div>
<div id="button" class="btn4">Button 4</div>
<div id="menu_to_show" class="menu4">
    Some text under button 4. <br/>
    New line of last text.
</div>
```

For example: I click on button 2, so I open menu 2. When I click on button 3, I open menu 3 but the previous menu 2 is still open.

**What should I do if I want to close the other menus when I click on a button?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do for example this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".btn1").click(function(){
        $('#menu_to_show').not('.menu1').hide();
        $(".menu1").toggle();
    });
    $(".btn2").click(function(){                  
        $('#menu_to_show').not('.menu2').hide();
        $(".menu2").toggle();
    });
    $(".btn3").click(function(){
        $('#menu_to_show').not('.menu3').hide();
        $(".menu3").toggle();
    });
    $(".btn4").click(function(){
        $('#menu_to_show').not('.menu4').hide();
        $(".menu4").toggle();
    });
});
```

Though I would suggest using classes instead of IDs, something more common.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't had the code to close the open div's

Also HTML element's id should be unique and a class name should be shared with more than one element. your code seemed to have flipped this concept.I have corrected this in your HTML and CSS code. A correctly coded HTML & CSS would shorten your script and makes your maintenance job so much easier.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".btn").click(function() {
    //hide all the open div's
    $('.menu').filter(function(e) {
      return $(this).css("display") == "block";
    }).toggle();
    //open the correct div now
    $(this).next('.menu:first').toggle();
  });
});
```

```css
.btn {
  height: 35px;
  line-height: 35px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: grey;
  border-top: 2px solid white;
  border-bottom: 2px solid white;
}
.menu {
  border: 2px solid orange;
  height: 50px;
}
.menu {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="button1" class="btn">Button 1</div>
<div id="menu_to_show1" class="menu">
  This is text which belong to button 1.
</div>
<div id="button2" class="btn">Button 2</div>
<div id="menu_to_show2" class="menu">
  This is another text. This appear after you click on button 2.
</div>
<div id="button3" class="btn">Button 3</div>
<div id="menu_to_show3" class="menu">
  Some text under button 3.
</div>
<div id="button4" class="btn">Button 4</div>
<div id="menu_to_show4" class="menu">
  Some text under button 4.
  <br/>New line of last text.
</div>
```

Comment: This work nearly perfect ... BUT ... when you click again on for example button1 you can not hide menu1